# Select smoothing parameter and implement non-parametric regression in Python

Tags: python, r

I'm working in R to estimate non-parametric regression. The complete project: https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/classical-technical-patterns

My `R` code is the following , relying on the `sm` package's `h.select` and `sm.regression`.

```
library(sm)
y = as.vector( last( Cl(data), 190) )
t = 1:len(y)

h = h.select(t, y, method = 'cv')
temp = sm.regression(t, y, h=h, display = 'none')
```

I now would like to do the same in Python. I managed to set up the data (see below) but do not know how to select the smoothing parameter and estimate the non-parametric regression.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

start = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 24)

df = web.DataReader("^GSPC", 'yahoo', start, end)

y = df['Close'].tail(190).values
t = list(range(1, len(y) + 1))
```

Comment: I just added it @dspencer

Comment: Hello there, if you want to apply exactly the same method, you should first find out what the statistics in the `sm` package are. The documentation is a good starting point: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sm/sm.pdf. Then you can search if you find the identical method in Python.